# How long does Google process requests for API key of Google Maps SDK for iOS?

Tags: google-maps-sdk-ios

We've submitted online form https://developers.google.com/maps/ios-access back in Dec 2012 however we still have not received any response from Google.

Does anyone who posted similar request back in Dec know how long does it regularly take Google to reply to such requests?

If we know it, it will help us (and maybe others who posted similar questions) to plan on when we can start development of our iPhone app because

Unfortunately, self-service method for API key generation through API  Console suggested at "Obtaining an API Key" section of https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start does not work for us as we simply do not see "Google Maps SDK for iOS" in services list.

Also as of our verification (unless we did it in wrong way), SDK does not work without API key.

Answer (score 3):

I applied for access on the 13th of December, and then received an email saying I'd been approved on the 17th of December.

But I don't think this should be taken to mean that it takes 4 days to get approved.

Google are rolling out access to their SDK gradually. They may have received way more requests than they want to provide access to yet. Maybe they've already reached an initial quota, and are waiting for something (like releasing a new version, or optimizing their back end, etc) before releasing any more. Or maybe they are releasing them in batches of N per day or something. So it may take some time before anyone else gets approved.

Also I'm not sure if Google is releasing them on a first-come, first-served basis. The request form asks if you have an existing app on the app store. Maybe Google are releasing access based on if you have an app, and if you do, how popular it seems and/or how integral maps are to the app, or something like that.

So at this stage, I think all you can do is wait.